# PHP include with Global Variable Failing

Tags: php, include, global-variables, global

I am setting a global variable on my config.php page as follows:

```
$MAIN = substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))),   strlen(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))));
define ('MAIN', $MAIN);
```

on my php pages I am trying to include the files as follows:

```
include 'config.php';
include MAIN.'/functions.php';
```

However I am getting a Server Error and nothing is returned on the page.  If I replace the second include with echo:

```
include 'config.php';
echo MAIN.'/functions.php';
```

the page loads with the line :

```
/application/functions.php
```

printed at the top of the page.  This is the correct locations of the file I wish to include.
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: that is not a variable its a constant

Comment: what does this line do `$MAIN = substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))),   strlen(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))));`

Comment: include paths must be relative to the current directory, or absolute to the server root directory. You are trying to use a path absolute to the webroot, by cutting at DOCUMENT_ROOT, which won't work.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I don't really understand why this occurs though.  Surely the include command just reads the path and tries to include the file located there?  Any suggestion how to fix this?